# A pentagon using less than 5 lines

Tags: paper-folding

A pen and paper challenge:  Draw a pentagon on a piece of paper

- only draw straight lines
- draw less than 5 times!
- The pentagon has to be fully drawn in ink, on the paper in unfolded state.

I am not looking for creative answers, e.g.:

- do not move the paper while drawing a line
- ink does not leak though a next layer of the paper (if it is folded)!

The ideal answer:

- Shows how it is done
- Uses the minimum amount of lines possible
- Proves that is minimal

as bonus: Also tells/explains the minimum for an octagon

If a solution with a hole gives a better answer; I'd like both answers (i.e. with and without).

Comment: Is the paper rectangular?

Comment: I do not care (It can always made rectangular by folding but if other forms allow a better answer; I am interested)

Comment: Can the paper have a hole or be a non-convex shape?  That would be a creative answer, I guess.

Comment: Does it have to be a regular pentagon?  Or is every pentagon ok, convex or not.

Comment: Just to add. Holes, non-convex paper and non-convex pentagons were not on my mind when asking this question; but if they lead to interesting constructions; why not?

Comment: Submission for [MTC](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7388/monthly-topic-challenge-3-pencil-and-paper-games?cb=1)?

Comment: @Stiv The MTC did give me the idea direction, but it is not really a pen &paper GAME, is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After proving that 3 strokes are necessary, here is a solution in 2 strokes!

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: OK. I'm impressed. I totally bought the 3 line argument. This is beautiful.

Comment: I am accepting this answer. It is clear, surprising and optimal within my constraints; However, the other answers are useful too. They tackle the no-hole case. I do want to add though that those solutions do NOT work for the regular pentagon. Although not asked, and not proven by anyone:  4 lines are needed for a regular pentagon!

Comment: This also lets you do it in 1 stroke if you cut the ring to open it.

Answer (score 3):

> Label the corners of the paper ABCD in clockwise order. Draw a line from the midpoint of AB (label it E) to the midpoint of BC (label it F). Then AEFCD is a pentagon.

Comment: If this is correct, then you can create an octagon by rot13(hfvat sbhe yvarf, bar arne rnpu bs gur cncre'f sbhe pbearef).

Comment: I guess that is a loophole in my formulation; I meant that the pentagon had to be fully drawn; I will adapt my question to be better formulated

Answer (score 3):

Method:

> It seems that we have a paper of finite size & folding is allowed.
>  We can fold the paper like D1 where the shaded area gets hidden:
>  When we make a single stroke with blue in D2, Perpendicular to the fold, we get two blue lines with a gap in the hidden area shown in D3, Perpendicular to the fold lines.
>  By changing the angle of the Stroke, we can make the two blue lines at some angle like in D4, where the 2 angles marked in Black are Equal.
>  By changing the angle of the folding, we get Blue lines which are not co-linear when unfolded , like in D5.
>  By changing both the angle of the Stroke & the angle of the folding, we get the 2 Green lines in D8.

> [image: PENTAGON]

Pentagon with 4 lines:

> We can fold the paper like D5 where the shaded area gets hidden:
>  When we make single stroke with blue in 2, we get two blue lines with a gap in the Shaded hidden area.
>  Draw 3 Orange lines arbitrarily to get the Pentagon in D6.

Pentagon with 3 lines:

> With one Stroke, we get 2 Blue lines in D7.
>  By the other fold indicated by the other Purple lines, we get 2 Green lines.
>  Lastly, use one Orange stroke to finish the Pentagon with 3 strokes.

OPTIMALITY:

> ! We can not draw Pentagon with 2 strokes in this method.
> We can only get alternate lines with a Stroke but there are only 2 Pairs of alternate lines here. The last line will require one Stroke.
> ! Total 3 is the Minimum.

Octagon with same technique:

> With 4 strokes : We can draw the Octagon with 4 strokes where each stroke gives 2 lines : Very Easy foldings !
>  With 3 strokes : We can get 3 alternate lines with 1 stroke by using 2 foldings at the same time : Moderately Complex foldings !
>  We can then get 3 more lines with 1 stroke again using 2 foldings at the same time.
>  We finish with the last stroke to get the last 2 lines. This Octagon uses 3 strokes.
>  With 2 strokes: It is Possible to get 4 alternate lines of Octagon with 1 stroke : Most Complex foldings !
>  We then get 4 more interleaving alternate lines with 1 stroke.
>  In this case we can draw the Octagon with 2 strokes.
>  This technique will not allow 1 Stroke.

Comment: Good ideas, but there is a complication that you have missed, or at least left unmentioned. In diagram 4 you will find that the purple lines will cross each other on the paper and the paper below that it will make it impossible to rotate the blue lines enough.

Comment: Actually, that is why we have to use a Paper of finite Size. Using the whole Plane, we will run into the Problem you mention. When using finite Size, the Purple lines will "cross", but at some Point outside the area. @Retudin

Comment: The blue one is fixable; and maybe I do not understand the meaning of purple. But the green ones as drawn are impossible, because whatever 2 points you choose as the ends of the green pen-stroke, they will be less far apart than the sum of the lengths of the parts. Perhaps you could show the actual folds more clearly?

Comment: Yes, the Green lines shown are valid only for the 4 Stroke Solution. In case of the 3 Stroke Solution, the lower Green line should be vertical, otherwise it is not Possible, like you observe. The Orange line is simple enough. The 2 Purple lines indicate folding. The Shaded Area gets hidden. In the 3 Stroke Solution, we have to use 2 more Purple lines to fold & get 2 Shaded Areas (but not at the same time) & get the 2 Green lines. Again the Orange line is last. I will try making the Diagrams clearer by tomorrow. @Retudin

Comment: Note that if you fold the purple lines upon each other; if one line part is orthogonal to the fold/its purple line; the other one is also orthogonal to the fold/the other purple line. That is clearly not the case in picture 4. This was the cause of my first remark; and something to also consider tomorrow  :-)

Comment: Oh, that is Correct ! I will ensure that Point ! @Retudin

Answer (score 2):

Let me do the octogon (aka octagon)

> Plan the octagon
>   [image]

> Fold the paper and draw a first line.
>  [image]

> Unfold
>  [image]

> Fold again and draw the second line.
>  [image]
>  Note only the 3 middle segments were drawn.

> Unfold and draw the third line.
>  [image]
>  The octagon is complete.

Minimality:

> What is certain is that you cannot do in one line.  Because you would have to "unfold" the polygon which you cannot do without tearing it.  I assume tearing or cutting the paper is not allowed.
>
>  In two lines, it would actually be possible if you have a star-shaped hole in the paper.  You could draw a polygon joining the points of the star and it could be stretched to a straight line, one half at a time.  But I assume a hole inside the paper is not allowed.
>
>  My proof for the pentagon relied on the fact that you cannot draw two adjacent segments in one stroke because you cannot straighten the angle between the segments without tearing the paper.
>  You cannot separate the pentagon's sides in 2 sets without any set including two adjacent sides.  Therefore 3 lines are necessary.
>
>  But it doesn't work because you can split each side of the pentagon in two and get 10 segments.  You can then separate these segments in two sets of 5, with no adjacent segments in either set.  So the proof doesn't hold.
>
>  But let's say you have divided your polygon into a loop of segments alternating between two colors.
>  The colors represent the 2 strokes you will draw.
>  Suppose somehow you manage to straighten them on a line to draw all segments of one color.
>  The loop must somehow go from one end of the line to the other and back.  It must cover the distance twice.  On the other side, hte length you can draw is only once the length of the line.
>  That means the total length you can draw in one stroke cannot exceed half of the loop length.  To draw all segments of the loop in two stokes, each stroke must draw exactly half of the loop length.
>  In other words, the line has exactly twice the length of one stroke.  In that situation, when you draw the line, the whole loop must be aligned with the line you are drawing.  It has no slack to do otherwise.
>  When the loop is straightened, any 2 segments that have an angle in the original polygon, must be straightened, except the two and the ends, but this is not possible without tearing the paper.
>
>  Conclusion: It is not possible to draw any polygon in 2 strokes.
>  It is possible however if you allow to cut the paper or if you allow a hole in the paper.

Comment: [ +1 ] This is similar to what I mention at the end of my Answer , but I want to make 4 alternate lines with 1 Stroke ; Symmetry then allows me to make 4 more alternate lines with 1 Stroke which will make the Octagon with only 2 Strokes ! I have not yet made a sketch to show it.

Comment: This is the easy to understand solution for any almost degenerate N-agon I also had in mind. But is it minimal? And if so why?

Answer (score 1):

This *may* count as too much of a "creative answer" for OP's liking, but…

### One Line (and a very blobby pen)

This method works best with something like a fibre-tip or felt-tip pen, and not a ballpoint pen or fountain pen (which rely on pressure/friction between the pen and the paper)

Here is the unfolded net of the paper:
[image: Unfolded net of paper with irregular pentagon in centre]

Here is the paper, folded so that all of the edges of the pentagon lie on the same edge of the result:  (Note that one of the lines is folded in half, back on itself)
[image: Paper folded such that all edges of the pentagon are adjacent mountain-folds]

Squeezed together with a peg and a paperclip, to bunch everything up as much as possible, a single thick line is drawn on the edge of the folded paper:
[image: The line has been drawn sloppily and blobbily, to cover all of the exposed edges]

The paper is then unfolded:
[image: The net has been unfolded, revealing that all of the crease-lines on the pentagon from the first image have been coloured]

Comment: I like the answer. It is creative, the technique is well explained, and the result looks good. However, i.m.o. it is indeed to much like the forbidden 'cheating' like "ink does not leak though a next layer of the paper (if it is folded)!"

Comment: @Retudin I suspected it might be, but it was largely an exercise in “*can* it be done?”